# Image not opening in python OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I tried to run simple code in python(3.6) open cv2 latest version. But when I want to show the image using cv2.imshow(), the image is not opened. And it says 'python is not responding', and shows an empty window.

[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfOMJ.jpg). I kept the images in the same folder as the code for simplicity, yet it doesn't work. And there's no error either. I am using 'Spyder' ide to write the code.
The code is as follows,

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
im= cv2.imread('pic.jpg', 1)
cv2.imshow('1', im)
```

Answer (score 1):

In cv2 `imshow()` should be followed by `cv2.waitKey()`

try this :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
im= cv2.imread('pic.jpg', 1)
cv2.imshow('1', im)
cv2.waitKey()
```